# ps command: how to know all the headers with their respective descriptions?

Tags: ps, options

Through the following valuable tutorial:

- [Ps Command in Linux (List Processes)](https://linuxize.com/post/ps-command-in-linux/)

If the `ps -ef` command is executed then the output has the following header:

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
...

...
```

In the same tutorial exists an explanation of the `STIME` column/header.

But through the `man ps` in the `STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS` section - and even doing a search in the same `man` through the `/STIME` search term, well the `STIME` term/column/header does **not** appear.

**Note** I am assuming it would happen for other columns/headers according the option(s) applied for the `ps` command. So ...

**Question**

- How is expected to know all the headers with their respective descriptions?

**Linux Distribution**

This scenario happens for Ubuntu Server 18:04 and 20:04

Comment: What operating system are you using? There are different `ps` implementations out there. I can see a line telling me that `STIME` means "start_time" in my `man ps` on a Linux system.

Comment: @terdon added the `Linux Distribution` section

Comment: Thanks, and yeah, I can confirm that an Ubuntu Server 18.04 I have access to lacks the `STIME` section in its man page, although my Arch install has it. A bug, as suggested by Stephen in his answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you’re using [the `procps` implementation of `ps`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) (which is the most common on Linux distributions you’re likely to be using), the headers are listed in [the “STANDARD FORMAT SPECIFIERS” section](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#STANDARD_FORMAT_SPECIFIERS).

`STIME` is documented [since version 3.3.17](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/9dd75a4ac851f7e99dd402323fb98771708cb201/NEWS#L64), released in February 2021:

```
stime       STIME     see start_time. (alias start_time).
```

The fact that it wasn’t documented until version 3.3.17 illustrates that it does happen that headers aren’t documented, but such cases are bugs.

You’ll get `procps` 3.3.17 or later in Ubuntu 21.10 and later.

Comment: Thanks **(1)** How do you know about the `3.3.17` version? - I can see  in the link shared that the `STIME` header appears, but nothing about the version mentioned. **(2)** Where I can see the source code of the `ps` command to see the list of releases? - github? **(3)** is possible update with some command the `ps` command? It expecting to get the latest version. Normally I use `apt` in Ubuntu.

Comment: @ManuelJordan, Ubuntu is a stable distro. No API change. In 18.04, you get an API from around 2018. Upgrade to 22.04 if you want an API from around 2022. Or get an unstable / rolling distro like Debian sid or opensuse tumbleweed to get new versions of software as they are being released and then packaged.

Comment: (2) `apt-cache showsrc procps` can help. duckduckgo as well.

Comment: (1) I found [the commit which added the line](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/commit/4c23fcfd3c3cfdb96134b3e2a6f659a6e307d6b5), which revealed that it was mentioned in the `NEWS` file as well (I’ve added the link in the answer). (2) The project is [hosted here](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps). (3) In Ubuntu, like other non-rolling-release distributions, you get whatever was packaged when the release was cut, and any essential fixes thereafter (for security issues or serious bugs).

Comment: Huge thanks for the quick and polite answer and support - about the `man` source and _"others"_ pls consider the following post [What is the official 'man' location in the web?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/701677/what-is-the-official-man-location-in-the-web) - thank you

Comment: Just a curious case, if is executed `ps -l` it shows the `ADDR` column/header, but its declaration and explanation does not appear neither [ps1 - man7.org](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html#STANDARD_FORMAT_SPECIFIERS) nor `man ps`

Comment: That’s because [the `ADDR` column doesn’t show any information at all](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/9dd75a4ac851f7e99dd402323fb98771708cb201/ps/output.c#L1618) (`pr_nop` always outputs “`-`”). It’s supposed to provide [the address of the process](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/9dd75a4ac851f7e99dd402323fb98771708cb201/ps/output.c#L279) but that’s either meaningless or too privileged (even for root) on most systems. See also [this `TODO` entry](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/9dd75a4ac851f7e99dd402323fb98771708cb201/Documentation/TODO#L27).